# typeof of a function not returning correct value but undefined

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In the following example I am adding a number to the `typeof` function, but result is `1undefined`. why?

```js
var y = 1;
if (function f(){}) {
  y += typeof f;
}
console.log(y);
```

**Expected Result:**

```
1function
```

**Actual Result:**

```
1undefined
```

Can someone help me out understanding how the result is not `1function`? I know that if block does not have its own scope, so no sense why in round braces the function is not visible outside the round braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function there is being evaluated as a *function expression* because it's in an `if` statement. Thus, it doesn't get hoisted, nor is it visible anywhere other than in its own function body. The inside of the `if` statement is expecting a value, so it's treated as an expression.

Only function declarations get hoisted and become visible anywhere in their block.

Answer (score 1):

The `f()` in the condition is a *function expression* not a *function declaration* and it is not hoisted. Thus `undefined` is added:

```js
var y = 1;
function f(){}
if (f) {
  y += typeof f;
}
console.log(y);
```